# AngularJS 1.1.5 - for ui-mask when input field is dirty but empty, ui-mask still puts $invalid = true making the form invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<input type="text" id="hPhoneContact" name="hPhoneContact" maxlength="15" 
       ng-required="false" ng-model="model.hPhoneContact" ng-disabled="noChange" 
       ui-mask="'(999) 999-9999'" placeholder="Home Phone">
```

I have above html in my view file, `form.fieldName.$invalid` becomes true and ui-mask adds these classes on input field - `ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-mask`. My question is when the input field is empty but dirty then why is ui-mask not setting that field to pristin or set it to something that indicates that the field is empty and hence don't check for ui-mask pattern.

Since my input field is not required, I don't want ui-mask to check for pattern validity when it's dirty but empty. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.